# How do I write an nfloat literal?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm porting my code to the new unified xamarin.ios api.

I have this as a parameter in a method.

```
nfloat fontSize = 0f
```

The compiler complains...

```
Error CS1750: Optional parameter expression of type `float' cannot be converted to parameter type `System.nfloat'
```

How do I write a literal for an optional parameter of nfloat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

The native types in Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Mac (`nfloat`, `nint`, `nuint`) are not intrinsic managed types, and thus you can't create constants of those types.

Comment: Thanks. that explains it well. Of course, just because it looks like an intrinsic in the IDE editor... does not make it one! So I guess the work around is to make the default parameter a float or double then cast it to nfloat in the method.

Comment: I just hit this same issue but found an annoying limitation when using the new native types in combination with optional parameters. myMethod(nint number = 0) doesn't work because of the lack of literals and you can't explicitly cast because it'll complain about not being constant.

Eventually had to bite the bullet and explicitly cast before calling the method